# iPhone iOS 6 - Dismissing a subview crashes

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios6, subview

I can't quite figure out what's going on but I have a view that displays a subview when a users selects a button. This subview then also has a button the user can select to cancel and remove this subview. When all of this happens, my app crashes when you attempt to close the subview.

This is my code:

From the main view that shows the subview when a button is selected -

```
-(IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Going to send a message....");

    CGRect frameBounds = [self.view bounds];

    float frameWidth = frameBounds.size.width;
    float frameHeight = frameBounds.size.height;
    float frameX = frameBounds.origin.x;
    //float frameY = frameBounds.size.height / 2;
    float frameY = frameBounds.size.height;

    float finalY = frameBounds.size.height / 1.75;

    MessageChooserController *chooser = [[MessageChooserController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessageChooser" bundle:nil];

    //Set the frame off the screen at the bottom
    chooser.view.frame = CGRectMake(frameX, frameY, frameWidth, frameHeight);

    [self.view addSubview:chooser.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{chooser.view.frame = CGRectMake(frameX, finalY, frameWidth, frameHeight);}];
}
```

As you can see this simply shows a new subview - MessageChooserController. Now this subview, MessageChooserController has a button to cancel this "action".

The header file for MessageChooserController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MessageChooserController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_sendEmail;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_sendText;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn_cancel;

-(IBAction)closeChooser:(id)sender;

@end
```

And its implementation:

```
#import "MessageChooserController.h"

@interface MessageChooserController ()

@end

@implementation MessageChooserController
@synthesize btn_cancel, btn_sendEmail, btn_sendText;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    /*
    [btn_cancel setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_delete_button.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:8.0f topCapHeight:0.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    */
    /*
    UIImage *cancelButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_delete_button"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(30,0,30,0)resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];

    [btn_cancel setBackgroundImage:cancelButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    */

}

-(IBAction)closeChooser:(id)sender{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

As you can see I have a simple method to close this subview, closeChooser. All of this compiles but when I select the cancel button on the subview my app crashes. I can't find anything anywhere about this.

Essentially I want to have a view display like it does when you select "Send message" from your contacts.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the crash log.

Comment: How do I go about getting the crash log?

Comment: There's nothing there. Just lldb and Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS....

Comment: Make the `btn_cancel` button with `strong` property.

Comment: Same issue. Nothing changed by making the btn_cancel strong.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this is calling `[self presentModalViewController:viewController]` on the parent view controller and then calling `[self dismissModalViewController]` when you want to hide it.

Comment: Ok. So how do I go about that?

Comment: You can add another view controller's view to your view.

Comment: The way you're talking about doesn't allow for me to slide up the subview like I want.